# How to read one file, extract matching data from another, and grep that content in third file

Tags: shell, text-processing

I want to combine data from three files that have whitespace-separated columns.

first file:

```
CYCLE_NUMBER    output
---------------------
32                1
28                2
```

second file:

```
DATALOG_OUTPUT    Time    CELL_TYPE    MUX_SELECT    CYCLE_NUMBER
-
DATALOG_OUTPUT    9500        0           0              32
DATALOG_OUTPUT    19500       1           4              12
DATALOG_OUTPUT    29500       2           8              28
```

third file:

```
MUX_SEL    CUTNO
-
8        combo_1
0        combo_2
12       combo_3
```

I want the output as

```
DATALOG_OUTPUT    Time    CELL_TYPE    MUX_SELECT    CYCLE_NUMBER    CUTNO
-
DATALOG_OUTPUT    9500        0           0              32         combo_2
DATALOG_OUTPUT    29500       2           8              28         combo_1
```

I want to implement the following process to create the desired output file. 
Repeatedly (for every cycle in the first file):

1. Read a cycle number from the first file.
2. `grep` (search for) that cycle number in the second file
   and extract/capture that row.  (In my attempt to solve this, shown below,
   I save the line in a temporary/intermediate file called `output_1`.)
3. Extract the mux_select value from that row.
4. `grep` for this mux_select value in the third file
   and extract/capture that row.  (In my attempt to solve this,
   I save the line in a temporary/intermediate file called `output_2`.)
5. `paste` the two lines, writing to the final output file.

I tried this by writing this script:

```
foreach cycle (`cat first_file | awk '{print $1}'`)
  set cycle_number = ` cat second_file | grep -w $cycle`
  echo $cycle_number >> output_1
  foreach mux (`cat output_1 | awk '{print $3}'`)
    set mux_select = ` cat third_file | grep -w $mux`
    echo $mux_select >> output_2
    paste output_1 output_2 >> output_file
  end
end
```

Comment: Have you tried anything? You’re more likely to get help if you try to solve this yourself, show us what you’ve tried, and explain where you got stuck. Hint: look at `join`. … … … … … … P.S. Do you really want both MUX_SELECT and MUXSEL in your output (when they’re the same thing)?  And why does the last line of your desired output say “8” and “combo_3”, when your third input file associates MUXSEL “8” with “combo_1”?

Comment: oh so sorry...it was my mistake..i edit the files again. and yes i tried by writing this script.

Comment: (1) I advise you to write shell scripts for the POSIX shell or bash, and not the C shell. (a) See [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot). (b) You’ll probably get better help on Stack Exchange for `sh` scripts than you will for `csh` scripts.  (2) You should always quote your shell variable references (e.g., `"$cycle"` and `"$cycle_number"`, etc.) unless you have a good reason not to, and you’re sure you know what you’re doing.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (3) You’re using `cat` ***way*** more than you need to; see [UUoC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat).  For example, `cat first_file | awk '{print $1}'` can be simplified to `awk '{print $1}' first_file`, and `cat second_file | grep -w $cycle` can be simplified to `grep -w "$cycle" second_file` (note the added quotes), etc.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (4) It’s often a good idea to put **`--`** between a command’s option(s) and its argument(s) — especially when the argument(s) come from outside the script (i.e., they come from user data, and are not known until run time).  This protects against argument(s) that begin with **`-`** and therefore “look like” options.  For example, `grep -w "$cycle" second_file` should be `grep -w -- "$cycle" second_file`.  In particular, this would prevent the error message that you’re currently getting when `$cycle` gets the value `---------------------` from the first file.  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (5) I’m not entirely clear how you expect the script to work.  I guess you want it to work one line (i.e., one cycle) at a time.  But, if that’s what you want, it doesn’t really make sense to say `>> output_1`, as that will build up output from one loop iteration to the next.  Consider `> output_1` instead.  (By the same argument, I believe that you should be doing `> output_2` rather than `>> output_2`.)   (6) Rather than ``cycle_number=`grep -w "$cycle" second_file` `` and `echo "$cycle_number" > output_1`, why not just do `grep -w -- "$cycle" second_file > output_1`?  … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (7) You are using `'{print $3}'` to extract mux values, but they are in the 4th column (so you should be using `'{print $4}'`).  (8) If you do everything I suggested above, ***and*** change the column heading in the third file from `MUX_SEL` to `MUX_SELECT`, you will get something very close to what you want.  While having your script process the column headers in your files can sometimes be very useful, it can also sometimes complicate matters.  Consider removing the column headers from your input files, and creating them on the output file explicitly. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  (In particular, you might want to get rid of the heading lines that begin with **`-`**.)  Also, you might want to delete the blank lines from your files (or else add code to your script to handle them). (9) Beware of cross-column values.  For example, if you have a cycle number of 8 or a mux_select of 12, you may get undesired results. … (Cont’d)

Answer (score 1):

Solution in [TXR](http://www.nongnu.org/txr):

Code in `join.txr`:

```
CYCLE_NUMBER    output
---------------------
@(collect)
@cycno @(skip)
@  (next)
@  (skip)
DATALOG_OUTPUT @time @cellt @muxsel @cycno
@  (next)
@  (skip)
@muxsel @cutno
@(end)
@(output)
DATALOG_OUTPUT    Time    CELL_TYPE    MUX_SELECT    CYCLE_NUMBER    CUTNO
-
@  (repeat)
DATALOG_OUTPUT    @{time 11}  @{cellt 11} @{muxsel   13} @{cycno 11}@cutno
@  (end)
@(end)
```

Run:

```
$ txr join.txr file1 file2 file3
DATALOG_OUTPUT    Time    CELL_TYPE    MUX_SELECT    CYCLE_NUMBER    CUTNO
-
DATALOG_OUTPUT    9500         0           0             32         combo_2
DATALOG_OUTPUT    29500        2           8             28         combo_1
```

Query only time 9500:

```
$ txr -Dtime=9500 join.txr file1 file2 file3
DATALOG_OUTPUT    Time    CELL_TYPE    MUX_SELECT    CYCLE_NUMBER    CUTNO
-
DATALOG_OUTPUT    9500         0           0             32         combo_2
```

Query only cycle number 28:

```
$ txr -Dcycno=28 join.txr file1 file2 file3
DATALOG_OUTPUT    Time    CELL_TYPE    MUX_SELECT    CYCLE_NUMBER    CUTNO
-
DATALOG_OUTPUT    29500        2           8             28         combo_1
```